# jenksinfile to post long comment in multiple lines using gerrits plugin

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, gerrit-trigger, sonar-gerrit

I am using gerrits plugin to post comments to gerrit. how to post a new line or say, break the comment into multiple newlines?

below is going as a comment on gerrit as single line. I want to break it in two 3 lines. how would i?

```
noIssuesTitleTemplate  : "SonarQube Evaluations.....violations have not been found. CodeCOV on New Code: ${codeCoveragePercent}% and Duplicated Lines on New Code ${codeDuplicates}",
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the extra information provided that the Gerrit plugin being used is the [jenkinsci / sonar-gerrit-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/sonar-gerrit-plugin)

Add the newline character as `\n\n\n` into your template, append it to the part of the comment where you want to start the next line of the comment.

In your example, to break the comment into 3 lines it will be like the following:

```bash
noIssuesTitleTemplate: 'SonarQube Evaluations.....violations have not been found.\n\n\nCodeCOV on New Code: ${codeCoveragePercent}% and\n\n\nDuplicated Lines on New Code ${codeDuplicates}'
```

This will appear on Gerrit:

```bash
SonarQube Evaluations.....violations have not been found.
CodeCOV on New Code: ${codeCoveragePercent}% and 
Duplicated Lines on New Code ${codeDuplicates}
```

Note, that single quotes are used based on the Github page for the plugin, this should ensure that the line breaks are preserved and passed as separate lines to the Gerrit plugin.

Comment: it does not do it. i feel like this comment is passed to gerrit server and that has to decide how to break lines. so what should be set for gerrit server to break lines?

Comment: How are you sending the comment ? Are you doing - ```ssh -p <port> <gerrit.server> ...```, just wondering what the full command is to the server

Comment: the comment is posted by `sonar-gerrit` plugin. https://github.com/jenkinsci/sonar-gerrit-plugin

Comment: try this - ```noIssuesTitleTemplate  : 'SonarQube Evaluations.....violations have not been found.\n\n\nCodeCOV on New Code: ${codeCoveragePercent}% and\n\n\nDuplicated Lines on New Code ${codeDuplicates}',```

Comment: no luck. just prints this the above line as is. I have to use double quote for var expansion.

Comment: OK - out of the box thinking here - shall we try 1: ```"'SonarQube Evaluations.....violations have not been found.\n\n\nCodeCOV on New Code: ' ${codeCoveragePercent} '% and\n\n\nDuplicated Lines on New Code' ${codeDuplicates}"```

Comment: Also try 2: ```"SonarQube Evaluations.....violations have not been found.<br>CodeCOV on New Code: ${codeCoveragePercent}% and<br>Duplicated Lines on New Code ${codeDuplicates}"```

Comment: no dice again. it prints `<br>` as is in title.